# Mahjong Set of Blocks Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a set of blocks from the given dimensions of the user.The code displays one box in the begining and the submission form but not the blocks and i'm not sure what's wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
<title >MAHJONG GAME</title>
<div class="boxed" id="div1">
</div>
<form name= "dimensions" onSubmit="board()"> 
<p style="color:black">Type the number of cols you want</p> 
<input type="number" name="col" /> 
<p style="color:black">Type the number of rows you want</p> 
<input type="number" name="row" />  
<p>    </p>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />  
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
function board(){
for(var i=1;i<=document.dimensions.getElementsByName("col")[0].value;i=i+2){
for(var j=1;j<=document.dimensions.getElementsByName("row")[0].value;j=j+2){
var box = document.createElement("div");
box.class="boxed";
var a=document.createTextNode(Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1));
box.appendChild(a);
var element=document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(box);
}
}

</script>

<style type="text/css"> 
body {background-color:white;}
.boxed {
width: 10px;
padding: 10px;
margin:1px;
border:10px solid pink;
background-color: pink;
border-style:outset;
}
</style>
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that when you hit the submit button, the page reloads and doesn't process your script. I wrote this very quickly so the code can be cleaned up a bit. For clarity sake, I created a function that gets the values from the inputs and creates the board. Then I created a function to populate your board:

```
    function createBoard()
{
    var InputColValue = document.getElementById('col').value;
    var InputRowValue = document.getElementById('row').value;
    board(InputColValue, InputRowValue); 
};  

function board(col, row) {
    for (var i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        newDiv = document.createElement("div");
        divCol = "col"+i+" col-format";
        newDiv.className = divCol ;
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(newDiv);

        for (var j = 0; j < row; j++) {
            newDiv = document.createElement("div");
            newDiv.className = "boxed";
            document.getElementsByClassName(divCol)[0].appendChild(newDiv);
        }
    }   
};
```

Then for your CSS you would want to put the appropriate formatting to create your column and rows:

```
.col-format {
    float: left;
}

.boxed {
    width: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin:1px;
    border:10px solid pink;
    background-color: pink;
    border-style:outset;
}
```

Within the body of your HTML, instead of using the submit input type, use the input type button, with an onclick event that would fire the createBoard() function:

```
<form> 

    <label>Type the number of col you want</label>
    <input id="col" type="number" name="col" /> 
    <br>
    <label>Type the number of rows you want</label>
    <input id="row" type="number" name="row" /> 
    <br>
    <input type="button" onclick="createBoard()" value="Submit">

</form>
```

That should do it.

Comment: thank you very much,but if I want to generate random numbers on the blocks,how can I achieve that?I used this but I don't think it works   var a=document.createTextNode(Math.floor((Math.random()*10)+1));

Comment: I am trying to understand what kind script you want to write. Do you want users to either choose the number of rows/columns and also allow them to generate random number of blocks between 1-10?

Comment: Users only choose the number of rows/columns.Then the computer creates blocks with random letters or numbers on them.Each letter or number must be created at least twice so that when you click two of them, with the same letter or number, they disappear(just like in mahjong game).